# Why do my button links share the same line with headings in tablet view?

Tags: html, css, grid, responsive

I've marked this as unsolved again - the solution suggested last night worked really well to put things where they should be in the mobile & tablet views, but then it messes up the desktop view. Would anyone please take a peek at this and see if you know why? Thanks so much!

I'm really hoping you can help. Trying to cobble together a responsive web page. It looks fine in desktop mode, but in tablet mode, the blue buttons (lunch menu, dinner menu and drinks) seem to share the line with the next header (so lunch menu is seen next to Dinner Menu header, and so on). Here is my HTML and CSS:

```css
/*
BASE (MOBILE) SIZE
*/

/* typography */
body{
 color:#666;
 font-family:'Ubuntu', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
 font-size:1em;
 line-height:1.4em; 
 font-weight:normal;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
 font-weight:normal;
 font-family:'Droid Serif', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
 line-height:1.5em;
 margin:.45em 0;
 padding:0;
} 


/* links */
a,
a:visited,
a:active,
a:hover{color:#0099ff;}
a:hover{ text-decoration:none;}


/* Box sizing. */
*{ box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;}

  
/* structure */   
.wrapper{
 width: 92%; 
 margin: 0 auto;
}
header{ 
 padding:15px 0;
}
#banner{ 
 text-align:center;
}
 
#hero,
#page-header{
 background:#f3f3f3;
 border-top:1px solid #e2e2e2;
 border-bottom:1px solid #e2e2e2;
 padding:20px 0;
}
#hero h1{ 
 line-height:1.2em;
 margin-top:0px;
 margin-bottom:10px;}

#content {  
 margin:40px 0;
}

p{ margin:0 0 1.5em;}


/* RESPONSIVE IMAGES */
img{ max-width:100%; height:auto;}


/*MAIN MENU*/
.menu-toggle{
 display:block;
 padding:10px;
 margin:20px 0 0;
 background:#666;
 color:#fff;
 cursor:pointer;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 font-size:20px;
}
.menu-toggle.toggled-on{
 background:#0099ff;
}
.top-menu{
 display:none;
} 
.top-menu.toggled-on{
 display:block;
 position:relative;
 z-index:10;
}

.top-menu{
 clear:both;
 margin-bottom:60px;
 
}
.top-menu li a {
 background:#dadada;
 display:block;
 margin:1px 0; 
 padding:10px;
 text-decoration:none;
}
.top-menu li a:hover{
 background:#0099ff;
 color:#fff;
}
.top-menu li li a {
 background:#e8e8e8;
 padding-left:40px;
}
.top-menu li li li a {
 background:#efefef;
 padding-left:80px;
}



/*SPACE GRID ELEMENTS VERTICALLY, SINCE THEY ARE ONE UNDER ANOTHER SO FAR*/
.grid_1,
.grid_2,
.grid_3,
.grid_4,
.grid_5,
.grid_6,
.grid_7,
.grid_8,
.grid_9,
.grid_10,
.grid_11,
.grid_12 {
 margin-bottom:40px;
 /*positioning and padding*/
 position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

/*FOOTER*/
footer{  
 clear:both;
 font-size:80%;
 padding:20px 0;
 align-content: center;
}
footer ul{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 align-content: center;
}

/*colors and backgrounds*/
body{
 background:#fff;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
 color:#333; 
}

footer{ 
 background:#333;
 color:#ccc;
 align-content: center;
}
footer h1, footer h2, footer h3, footer h4{ 
 color:#CCC; 
 margin-bottom:10px;
}
footer ul{
 margin:0 0 0 8%;
 align-content: center;
}

a.buttonlink{ 
 background:#0099ff; 
 border-radius:7px; 
 color:#fff;
 display:block;
 float:left; 
 margin:10px 15px 10px 0; 
 padding:10px;
 text-decoration:none;
}
a.buttonlink:hover{
 background:#CCCCCC;
}



/* Contain floats*/ 
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after,
.row:before,
.row:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.clearfix:after,
.container:after,
.row:after{
  clear: both;
}



/*
TABLET & SMALLER LAPTOPS
*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 920px) {

.wrapper{
 max-width: 1200px; 
 margin: .75em auto;
}

#banner{ 
 float:left; 
 text-align:left;
 margin-bottom:0px;
}
header{
 padding:0;
}
#content {  
 float:left;
 width:65%;
}
#content.wide-content{
 float:none;
 width:100%;
}

aside { 
 float:right;
 width:30%;
}

/*** MAIN MENU - ESSENTIAL STYLES ***/
.menu-toggle{display:none;}
#menu-main-navigation{display:block;}

.top-menu, .top-menu * {
 margin:   0;
 padding:  0;
 list-style:  none;
}
.top-menu ul {
 position:  absolute;
 display:none;
 width:   12em; 
}
.top-menu ul li {
 width:   100%;
}
.top-menu li:hover {
 visibility:  inherit; 
}
.top-menu li {
 float:   left;
 position:  relative;
 margin-left:1px;
}
.top-menu li li {
 margin-left:0px;
}
.top-menu a {
 display:  block;
 position:  relative;
}
.top-menu li:hover ul,
.top-menu li.sfHover ul {
 display:block;
 left:   0;
 top:   45px; /* match top ul list item height */
 z-index:  99;
 -webkit-box-shadow:  2px 3px 2px 0px rgba(00, 00, 00, .3);
    box-shadow:  2px 3px 2px 0px rgba(00, 00, 00, .3);
}
ul.top-menu li:hover li ul,
ul.top-menu li.sfHover li ul {
 top:   -999em;
}
ul.top-menu li li:hover ul,
ul.top-menu li li.sfHover ul {
 left:   12em; /* match ul width */
 top:   0;
}
ul.top-menu li li:hover li ul,
ul.top-menu li li.sfHover li ul {
 top:   -999em;
}
ul.top-menu li li li:hover ul,
ul.top-menu li li li.sfHover ul {
 left:   10em; /* match ul width */
 top:   0;
}

#topnav, .top-menu {
 float:right;
 margin: .35em 0 0 0;
}
.top-menu a {
 text-decoration:none;
}
.top-menu li a {
 background:#fff;
 margin:0; 
 padding:10px 20px;
 height:45px;
}
.top-menu a, .top-menu a:visited  { 
 color:   #0099ff; 
}
.top-menu li li a {
  border-top:  1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.2);
  background:  #333; /*IN CASE VIEWED ON OLD IE*/
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.6);
  color: #fff;
  padding-left:20px;
  height:auto;
}
.top-menu li li a:visited{color:#fff;}
.top-menu li li li a,
.top-menu li.current * li a{
 padding-left:20px;
 background:rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}

.top-menu li:hover > a,
.top-menu li.current a{ 
 color:#fff;
 background:#0099ff;
}
.top-menu li li:hover > a{
 color:#fff;
 background:#0099ff;
}



/*GRID*/
/*  & Columns : 12 */
 .row{
  margin-left: -15px;
     margin-right: -15px;
}
 
.grid_1 { width: 8.33333333%; }
.grid_2 { width: 16.66666667%; }
.grid_3 { width: 25%; }
.grid_4 { width: 33.33333333%; }
.grid_5 { width: 41.66666667%; }
.grid_6 { width: 50%; }
.grid_7 { width: 58.33333333%; }
.grid_8 { width: 66.66666667%; }
.grid_9 { width: 75%; }
.grid_10 { width: 83.33333333%; }
.grid_11 { width: 91.66666667%; }
.grid_12 { width: 100%; }

.grid_1,
.grid_2,
.grid_3,
.grid_4,
.grid_5,
.grid_6,
.grid_7,
.grid_8,
.grid_9,
.grid_10,
.grid_11,
.grid_12 {
 float: left;
 display: block;
}

.rightfloat{float:right;}

#hero [class*="grid_"] { margin-bottom:-20px;}

}

/* DESKTOP*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 1030px) {

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

<title>GREKOS' GREEK RESTAURANT</title>
<meta name="description" content="Grekos' Restaurant is a family-owned restaurant in Regina, Saskatchewan serving authentic Greek food.">
<meta name="keywords" content="Greek restaurant Regina">

<!-- Mobile viewport -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">


<!-- CSS-->
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/basic-style.css">
<!-- end CSS-->


</style>
</head>

<body id="home">

    <header class="wrapper clearfix">         
        <div id="banner">        
         <div id="logo"><a href="#"><img src="images/grekoslogo.png" alt="Grekos Logo" width="80"/></a></div> 
        </div>
        
 
        <nav id="topnav" role="navigation">
          <div class="menu-toggle">Menu</div>  
          <ul class="top-menu" id="menu-main-navigation">
              <li class="current"><a href="basic.html">Home page</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Menus</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Reservations</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
              </li> 
          </ul>     
  </nav>
  
    </header>
 
 

    <section id="hero" class="clearfix">    
  
    <div class="wrapper">
       <div class="row"> 
        <div class="grid_5">
            <h1>Grekos' Greek Restaurant</h1>
            <h3><i>Come Taste The Difference!</i></h3>
            <p>Since 1979, Grekos' has been serving Regina patrons with tasty, authentic Greek food. The dream of George, Bob and Chris, three brothers from the Peloponnese region of southern greece, Grekos has earned the reputation of being one of Regina's outstanding restaurants - and more. It has become a gathering place for groups, business meetings, and family memories.</p>

   <p>The real test for any restaurant is that people want to come back," said George. "that is wht we strive to achieve every day."</p>

    <p>From the moment you step through the front doors, you enter a whole new world, with a cosy, relaxing ambiance, tantalizing food and always, a warm welcome. </p>
   <p><a href="#" class="buttonlink">SPECIAL EVENTS</a></p> 
         <p><a href="#" class="buttonlink">CALL FOR RESERVATIONS</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_7 rightfloat">
                         <img src="images/interior.jpg" alt="Grekos interior picture" />
                          <p class="flex-caption">Grekos offers a warm, welcoming atmosphere.</p>
                      
                        
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
    </section>





<!-- main content area -->   
<div id="main" class="wrapper">
    
    
<!-- content area -->    
 <section id="content" class="wide-content">
      <div class="row"> 
        <div class="grid_4">
          <h1 class="first-header">Lunch Menu</h1>
            <img src="images/greeksalad.jpg" alt="Lunch Menu, Greek Salad photo
" width="400" />
            <p>Quick service, a welcoming atmosphere and authentic Greek cuisine make Grekos' your "go to" lunch destination.</p>
            <p><a href="#" class="buttonlink">Lunch Menu</a></p> 
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid_4">
          <h1 class="first-header">Dinner Menu</h1>
            <img src="images/souvlaki.png" width="400" />
            <p>Treat yourself and your family to traditional Hellenic (Greek) meals - we guarantee a memorable dining experience at affordable prices.</p>
            <p><a href="#" class="buttonlink">Dinner Menu</a></p>
            
        </div>
     
        <div class="grid_4">
         <h1 class="first-header">Drinks, Coffees & Desserts</h1>
            <img src="images/drinks.png" width="400" />
            <p>Accompany your meal with one of our refreshing beverages, and cap it off with our delectable desserts, including Baklava and Galaktoboureko... and of course, don't forget your Greek coffee afterward!</p>
            <p><a href="#" class="buttonlink">Drinks, Coffees & Desserts Menu</a></p> 
        </div>
   </div>
 </section>      
         
  </div>


<!-- footer area -->    
<footer>
 <div class="wrapper clearfix">
     <b>Grekos' Greek Restaurant </b> 4410 Albert Street, Regina  |  306.584.3646
    </div>
   
</footer><!-- #end footer area --> 


</body>
</html>
```

Thanks so much for any insight you can provide!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Not the best solution but you needed `clear:both` on `.grid_4` class to eliminate any floating elements, which fixes the issue.

You will need to update your CSS in this section:

```
/*SPACE GRID ELEMENTS VERTICALLY, SINCE THEY ARE ONE UNDER ANOTHER SO FAR*/
.grid_1,
.grid_2,
.grid_3,
.grid_4,
.grid_5,
.grid_6,
.grid_7,
.grid_8,
.grid_9,
.grid_10,
.grid_11,
.grid_12 {
    margin-bottom:40px;
    /*positioning and padding*/
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    clear:both;            /* <----- THIS LINE WAS ADDED */
}
```

**Preview:**

```css
/*
BASE (MOBILE) SIZE
*/

/* typography */
body{
 color:#666;
 font-family:'Ubuntu', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
 font-size:1em;
 line-height:1.4em; 
 font-weight:normal;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
 font-weight:normal;
 font-family:'Droid Serif', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
 line-height:1.5em;
 margin:.45em 0;
 padding:0;
} 


/* links */
a,
a:visited,
a:active,
a:hover{color:#0099ff;}
a:hover{ text-decoration:none;}


/* Box sizing. */
*{ box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;}

  
/* structure */   
.wrapper{
 width: 92%; 
 margin: 0 auto;
}
header{ 
 padding:15px 0;
}
#banner{ 
 text-align:center;
}
 
#hero,
#page-header{
 background:#f3f3f3;
 border-top:1px solid #e2e2e2;
 border-bottom:1px solid #e2e2e2;
 padding:20px 0;
}
#hero h1{ 
 line-height:1.2em;
 margin-top:0px;
 margin-bottom:10px;}

#content {  
 margin:40px 0;
}

p{ margin:0 0 1.5em;}


/* RESPONSIVE IMAGES */
img{ max-width:100%; height:auto;}


/*MAIN MENU*/
.menu-toggle{
 display:block;
 padding:10px;
 margin:20px 0 0;
 background:#666;
 color:#fff;
 cursor:pointer;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 font-size:20px;
}
.menu-toggle.toggled-on{
 background:#0099ff;
}
.top-menu{
 display:none;
} 
.top-menu.toggled-on{
 display:block;
 position:relative;
 z-index:10;
}

.top-menu{
 clear:both;
 margin-bottom:60px;
 
}
.top-menu li a {
 background:#dadada;
 display:block;
 margin:1px 0; 
 padding:10px;
 text-decoration:none;
}
.top-menu li a:hover{
 background:#0099ff;
 color:#fff;
}
.top-menu li li a {
 background:#e8e8e8;
 padding-left:40px;
}
.top-menu li li li a {
 background:#efefef;
 padding-left:80px;
}



/*SPACE GRID ELEMENTS VERTICALLY, SINCE THEY ARE ONE UNDER ANOTHER SO FAR*/
.grid_1,
.grid_2,
.grid_3,
.grid_4,
.grid_5,
.grid_6,
.grid_7,
.grid_8,
.grid_9,
.grid_10,
.grid_11,
.grid_12 {
 margin-bottom:40px;
 /*positioning and padding*/
 position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    clear:both;            /* <----- THIS LINE WAS ADDED */
}

/*FOOTER*/
footer{  
 clear:both;
 font-size:80%;
 padding:20px 0;
 align-content: center;
}
footer ul{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 align-content: center;
}

/*colors and backgrounds*/
body{
 background:#fff;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
 color:#333; 
}

footer{ 
 background:#333;
 color:#ccc;
 align-content: center;
}
footer h1, footer h2, footer h3, footer h4{ 
 color:#CCC; 
 margin-bottom:10px;
}
footer ul{
 margin:0 0 0 8%;
 align-content: center;
}

a.buttonlink{ 
 background:#0099ff; 
 border-radius:7px; 
 color:#fff;
 display:block;
 float:left; 
 margin:10px 15px 10px 0; 
 padding:10px;
 text-decoration:none;
}
a.buttonlink:hover{
 background:#CCCCCC;
}



/* Contain floats*/ 
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after,
.row:before,
.row:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.clearfix:after,
.container:after,
.row:after{
  clear: both;
}



/*
TABLET & SMALLER LAPTOPS
*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 920px) {

.wrapper{
 max-width: 1200px; 
 margin: .75em auto;
}

#banner{ 
 float:left; 
 text-align:left;
 margin-bottom:0px;
}
header{
 padding:0;
}
#content {  
 float:left;
 width:65%;
}
#content.wide-content{
 float:none;
 width:100%;
}

aside { 
 float:right;
 width:30%;
}

/*** MAIN MENU - ESSENTIAL STYLES ***/
.menu-toggle{display:none;}
#menu-main-navigation{display:block;}

.top-menu, .top-menu * {
 margin:   0;
 padding:  0;
 list-style:  none;
}
.top-menu ul {
 position:  absolute;
 display:none;
 width:   12em; 
}
.top-menu ul li {
 width:   100%;
}
.top-menu li:hover {
 visibility:  inherit; 
}
.top-menu li {
 float:   left;
 position:  relative;
 margin-left:1px;
}
.top-menu li li {
 margin-left:0px;
}
.top-menu a {
 display:  block;
 position:  relative;
}
.top-menu li:hover ul,
.top-menu li.sfHover ul {
 display:block;
 left:   0;
 top:   45px; /* match top ul list item height */
 z-index:  99;
 -webkit-box-shadow:  2px 3px 2px 0px rgba(00, 00, 00, .3);
    box-shadow:  2px 3px 2px 0px rgba(00, 00, 00, .3);
}
ul.top-menu li:hover li ul,
ul.top-menu li.sfHover li ul {
 top:   -999em;
}
ul.top-menu li li:hover ul,
ul.top-menu li li.sfHover ul {
 left:   12em; /* match ul width */
 top:   0;
}
ul.top-menu li li:hover li ul,
ul.top-menu li li.sfHover li ul {
 top:   -999em;
}
ul.top-menu li li li:hover ul,
ul.top-menu li li li.sfHover ul {
 left:   10em; /* match ul width */
 top:   0;
}

#topnav, .top-menu {
 float:right;
 margin: .35em 0 0 0;
}
.top-menu a {
 text-decoration:none;
}
.top-menu li a {
 background:#fff;
 margin:0; 
 padding:10px 20px;
 height:45px;
}
.top-menu a, .top-menu a:visited  { 
 color:   #0099ff; 
}
.top-menu li li a {
  border-top:  1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.2);
  background:  #333; /*IN CASE VIEWED ON OLD IE*/
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.6);
  color: #fff;
  padding-left:20px;
  height:auto;
}
.top-menu li li a:visited{color:#fff;}
.top-menu li li li a,
.top-menu li.current * li a{
 padding-left:20px;
 background:rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}

.top-menu li:hover > a,
.top-menu li.current a{ 
 color:#fff;
 background:#0099ff;
}
.top-menu li li:hover > a{
 color:#fff;
 background:#0099ff;
}



/*GRID*/
/*  & Columns : 12 */
 .row{
  margin-left: -15px;
     margin-right: -15px;
}
 
.grid_1 { width: 8.33333333%; }
.grid_2 { width: 16.66666667%; }
.grid_3 { width: 25%; }
.grid_4 { width: 33.33333333%; }
.grid_5 { width: 41.66666667%; }
.grid_6 { width: 50%; }
.grid_7 { width: 58.33333333%; }
.grid_8 { width: 66.66666667%; }
.grid_9 { width: 75%; }
.grid_10 { width: 83.33333333%; }
.grid_11 { width: 91.66666667%; }
.grid_12 { width: 100%; }

.grid_1,
.grid_2,
.grid_3,
.grid_4,
.grid_5,
.grid_6,
.grid_7,
.grid_8,
.grid_9,
.grid_10,
.grid_11,
.grid_12 {
 float: left;
 display: block;
}

.rightfloat{float:right;}

#hero [class*="grid_"] { margin-bottom:-20px;}

}

/* DESKTOP*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 1030px) {

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

<title>GREKOS' GREEK RESTAURANT</title>
<meta name="description" content="Grekos' Restaurant is a family-owned restaurant in Regina, Saskatchewan serving authentic Greek food.">
<meta name="keywords" content="Greek restaurant Regina">

<!-- Mobile viewport -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">


<!-- CSS-->
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/basic-style.css">
<!-- end CSS-->


</style>
</head>

<body id="home">

    <header class="wrapper clearfix">         
        <div id="banner">        
         <div id="logo"><a href="#"><img src="images/grekoslogo.png" alt="Grekos Logo" width="80"/></a></div> 
        </div>
        
 
        <nav id="topnav" role="navigation">
          <div class="menu-toggle">Menu</div>  
          <ul class="top-menu" id="menu-main-navigation">
              <li class="current"><a href="basic.html">Home page</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Menus</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Reservations</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
              </li> 
          </ul>     
  </nav>
  
    </header>
 
 

    <section id="hero" class="clearfix">    
  
    <div class="wrapper">
       <div class="row"> 
        <div class="grid_5">
            <h1>Grekos' Greek Restaurant</h1>
            <h3><i>Come Taste The Difference!</i></h3>
            <p>Since 1979, Grekos' has been serving Regina patrons with tasty, authentic Greek food. The dream of George, Bob and Chris, three brothers from the Peloponnese region of southern greece, Grekos has earned the reputation of being one of Regina's outstanding restaurants - and more. It has become a gathering place for groups, business meetings, and family memories.</p>

   <p>The real test for any restaurant is that people want to come back," said George. "that is wht we strive to achieve every day."</p>

    <p>From the moment you step through the front doors, you enter a whole new world, with a cosy, relaxing ambiance, tantalizing food and always, a warm welcome. </p>
   <p><a href="#" class="buttonlink">SPECIAL EVENTS</a></p> 
         <p><a href="#" class="buttonlink">CALL FOR RESERVATIONS</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_7 rightfloat">
                         <img src="images/interior.jpg" alt="Grekos interior picture" />
                          <p class="flex-caption">Grekos offers a warm, welcoming atmosphere.</p>
                      
                        
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
    </section>





<!-- main content area -->   
<div id="main" class="wrapper">
    
    
<!-- content area -->    
 <section id="content" class="wide-content">
      <div class="row"> 
        <div class="grid_4">
          <h1 class="first-header">Lunch Menu</h1>
            <img src="images/greeksalad.jpg" alt="Lunch Menu, Greek Salad photo
" width="400" />
            <p>Quick service, a welcoming atmosphere and authentic Greek cuisine make Grekos' your "go to" lunch destination.</p>
            <p><a href="#" class="buttonlink">Lunch Menu</a></p> 
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid_4">
          <h1 class="first-header">Dinner Menu</h1>
            <img src="images/souvlaki.png" width="400" />
            <p>Treat yourself and your family to traditional Hellenic (Greek) meals - we guarantee a memorable dining experience at affordable prices.</p>
            <p><a href="#" class="buttonlink">Dinner Menu</a></p>
            
        </div>
     
        <div class="grid_4">
         <h1 class="first-header">Drinks, Coffees & Desserts</h1>
            <img src="images/drinks.png" width="400" />
            <p>Accompany your meal with one of our refreshing beverages, and cap it off with our delectable desserts, including Baklava and Galaktoboureko... and of course, don't forget your Greek coffee afterward!</p>
            <p><a href="#" class="buttonlink">Drinks, Coffees & Desserts Menu</a></p> 
        </div>
   </div>
 </section>      
         
  </div>


<!-- footer area -->    
<footer>
 <div class="wrapper clearfix">
     <b>Grekos' Greek Restaurant </b> 4410 Albert Street, Regina  |  306.584.3646
    </div>
   
</footer><!-- #end footer area --> 


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm so sorry for being stupid about this - where do I put the clear: both in the css, exactly? I've tried in a couple places and it doesn't seem to do anything for me. I've likely put it in the wrong place...

Comment: thank you SO much! You are my hero! I've spent a couple hours now staring at the CSS trying to figure it out. You are a rockstar!!!

Comment: @DMB66 Haha...Awesome.